# JavaScriptにおけるマーカー認識

Tags: javascript

JavaScriptでARのマーカー認識のみ使いたくて (3Dオブジェクトの表示は不必要)
jsartoolkit5とAR.jsを調べていたのですが、私が求めている要件ができるのかどうかも含めての情報が中々出てこないです。

##### 要件

- 同時に複数Webカメラからの画像情報に対応
  PCに複数のWebカメラを接続して同時に複数のタグに対して別々のカメラ映像を表示するところまでできています。
- 上記のカメラから画像データを取得してマーカーが認識/認識から外れたらこちらで作った処理を発火させたい
  どのカメラからでマーカーが認識したかの判別もできるようにしたい。
  発火させる処理側は完成済みです。

上記のライブラリだとカメラも含めて自動でカメラ映像の取得から動いて任意(id指定された)の`<video>`タグの情報からマーカー認識処理ができないように見えました。

上記でのライブラリでそのようなことができる場合にやり方もしくは別のライブラリでできるようでしたらその情報をいただきたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jsartoolkit5 だと `ARController.getUserMediaARController()` を使うとカメラ取得からになりますが、自分で管理したい場合は `new ARController()` の第1引数や、 `ARController.process()` の引数に `ImageElement` か `VideoElement` を渡せるようです。

https://github.com/artoolkitx/jsartoolkit5/blob/master/js/artoolkit.api.js#L78
https://github.com/artoolkitx/jsartoolkit5/blob/master/js/artoolkit.api.js#L153

Comment: いただいた情報を元に実装したところこちらで指定したVideoタグに表示しているカメラ映像からマーカー認識できました。
ありがとうございました。

Comment: よかったです。問題なければ回答の左側から、承認済みマークつけてもらえると助かります。